# Logging value changes in WPF Databinding to a Property

Tags: wpf, data-binding, logging

I have a question about WPF databinding notification

I have a checkbox which is two-way binded to a bool propery of an internal data model. What I want is to show a value changed message in the UI (let's say "SomeBoolParameter changes from true => false" ) whenever the property is changed.

I have implemented the INotificationPropertyChanged interface in the data model and I know that I can get notified by setting SourceUpdated in the XAML.

However, the EventArgs that I can received in the SourceUpdated event is a DataTransferEventArgs object, which I don't know how to retrieve the data model property value from it.

Of coz, I can place the logging code in the property setter... but definity it is an ugly solution. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I want my data model is a pure model object to store the data.. That's y I feel like violating separation of concern when mixing the logging code with the model

Answer (score 0):

Why are you saying that it is an ugly solution? 
The setter is called each time you change the object value. If you want to follow an appropriate MVVM architecture, the only (and clean) way to do that is in the setter

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the DataTransferEventArgs has both a Property and a Source. Couldn't you just simply do something like this?

```
DependencyObject source = args.Source as DependencyObject;
if(source != null)
   DoSomething(source.GetValue(args.Property));
```

Comment: Really thx for ur help. Your code partially solved my problem. It works fine when the binding is a Textbox. But for Checkbox, it does not work.. It seems like WPF updates the IsChecked property after calling the SourceUpdatedTrigger. When calling the `source.GetValue(args.Property)`, it will return the old value ... sigh

Answer (score 0):

Putting your logging code on the Setter isn't ugly. Your setters/getters should be generated by some sort of mechanism, either LInq2SQL, Entity Framework, or some other flavor or ORM, this means you can tweak the generator to put custom logging code on all setters.

If you don't use ORM, and you should allways use it, a more shiny solution is to use Interception, though it will feel like you're requesting a Tank to kill a fly. There's a very good article on using Interception with Unity 2.0 [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg535676.aspx).